# Can an ETH transfer get blocked?

Tags: transfer, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, transferfrom, transfers-api

I minted 3 NFTs on [www.cosmicpace.com](http://www.cosmicpace.com) because a guy dm'd me on IG asking to buy them there. That went fine, but when I tried o withdraw the funds, I received an email from internalrevenueserviceirs@my.com saying the following and with this pdf-

Can eth transfers be blocked???

Hello, your withdrawal from Cosmicpace trading platform was blocked. Kindly check on the details on the attached file. We await your reply.

IRS

[image: letter attached to 'IRS' email]

Answer (score 1):

That's an obvious scam. Sorry but i believe you're never gonna see your money again :/ And don't pay anything else they might ask you to.

Comment: I haven't, and I tried to show Cosmicpace that this person is a scam but they're still not doing anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Cosmicspace is the scam, actually.

Answer (score 0):

That is an obvious scam.
Such intervention would not be sent by email but postal services, and through official avenues. I mean "dear Mr/Mrs. Crack3DFox" ... how can one fall for that ...

Comment: Yeah, this was sent AFTER I tried to withdraw my funds- 4.5 eth is being held uness I pay those amounts to this wallet- 0x8d44124da649D63d956f98a2605F571A2D8Fa533

I haven't sent anything, and when I tried to contact Cosmicpace about it they're telling me there's nothing they can do. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can report the business to IC3.gov and your local law enforcement. Recovery of funds is unlikely.